# Managing date in multiple culture language (C#)

Tags: datetime, rss, type-conversion, cultureinfo

I'm parsing multiple RSS feed and I need to get 'pubdate' from item, but for some of these dates I get format in different language, so my code fails if format language is not english.

with these kind of that of course it works:`enter code here`

```
Sun, 28 May 2017 14:44:06
```

with these dates doesn't work:

```
Dom, 28 Mag 2017 12:16:48
```

and here my piece of code:

```
String parseFormat = "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss";
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(pubDate, parseFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
pubDate = date.ToString("dd/MMM HH:mm:ss");
```

how can I manage multiple language in one code

Answer (score 0):

I've found that with this code you can get the date in any culture and then use it with your DateTime object:

```
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(pubDate);                
pubDate = date.ToString();
```

the format is

```
dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss
```

Answer (score 0):

The Solution i can think of is with every feed you need to set the date format and Culture, you can use any configuration source for it.
then use the code snippet below

```
String parseFormat = "ConfiguredFormatForthisRSSFeed"; 
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(pubDate, parseFormat, configuredCultureforthisRSSFeed);
pubDate = date.ToString("dd/MMM HH:mm:ss");
```